# Why doesn't Flowable.subscribe(Subscriber) return a Disposable?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java3

Most of the `Flowable.subscribe()` overloads return a `Disposable` which enable a flow to be cleaned up. I'm in the habit of doing:

```java
Disposable d = Flowable.just()
    .map(...)
    .subscribe(
        n -> ...
        t -> ...
        () -> ...
    );

// someone clicks "cancel" in another thread
d.dispose();
```

However, when using `.subscribe(Subscriber)` the `Disposable` is not returned. I'd like to use `.subscribe(Subscriber)` so I can pass in a `TestSubscriber` to verify behaviour. So how would I dispose the flow in this case?

I searched the Javadoc for appropriate `Subscriber`s. There's [`DisposableSubscriber`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/index.html?io/reactivex/rxjava3/subscribers/DisposableSubscriber.html) which looks like it would work, but two problems:

1. The class description reads as follows, which suggests `cancel()` cannot be used from outside a flow:

> Use the protected request(long) to request more items and **cancel() to cancel the sequence from within an onNext implementation**.

2. TestSubscriber does not extend DisposableSubscriber.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Flowable.subscribeWith(Subscriber)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Flowable.html#subscribeWith-E-) instead of `subscribe`, so that your `Subscriber` is returned, instead of `void`.

In RxJava 3.x `TestSubscriber` no longer implements `Disposable`. It does implement the [`dispose`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/subscribers/TestSubscriber.html#dispose--) and [`isDisposed`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/subscribers/TestSubscriber.html#isDisposed--) methods, as defined by `BaseTestConsumer`, which it extends. However, both of those methods have been made `protected`, so you can't actually use them directly. Luckily, there is [`TestSubscriber.cancel()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/subscribers/TestSubscriber.html#cancel--)/[`TestSubscriber.isCancelled()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/subscribers/TestSubscriber.html#isCancelled--), which are public, and are equivalent to `dispose()`/`isDisposed()`, so you can use those instead.

As for the reason `Flowable.subscribe` does not return a `Disposable`, this change was made in RxJava 2, [to adhere to the Reactive-Streams specification](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-2.0#subscriber):

> Due to the Reactive-Streams specification, `Publisher.subscribe` returns `void` ...To remedy this, the method `E subscribeWith(E subscriber)` has been added to each base reactive class which returns its input subscriber/observer as is.

Comment: Ok, and because the return type is parameterised I can pass a `Subscriber` that has a `dispose` method on it, e.g. `DisposableSubscriber`. However there's a problem here in that there's no a unifying type for the `DisposableSubscriber` and `TestSubscriber` - I guess I could wrap the latter in an adapter.

Comment: Also - is my concern about the `DisposableSubscriber` docs valid - _Use ... cancel() to cancel the sequence from within an onNext implementation_ - what if I'm doing it outside an `onNext()`?

Comment: You would use `DisposableSubscriber.dispose()` outside of `onNext()`.

Comment: re: the `DisposableSubscriber`/`TestSubscriber` type mismatch - I'm not sure what's going on there. In RxJava 2.x, `TestSubscriber` implements `Disposable`. I'm not sure why it no longer does in 3.x.

Comment: [Here's the PR where it was removed](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/6526). I'm still not sure why `dispose`/`isDisposed` were kept, but the `Disposable` interface was removed from the type hierarchy, though.

Comment: Oh, actually the `dispose` method was made `protected` - so that must be why it no longer implements `Disposable`. However, the `cancel()` method is still public, [and `dispose()` internally just delegates to `cancel()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/3.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/rxjava3/subscribers/TestSubscriber.java#L241).

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll try writing a couple of adapters and probably still store it typed as a `Disposable` given that's all I want to do to it.